# Figure captions stagger out of margin in List of Figures using package titletoc

Tags: titletoc

Figure captions stagger out of margin in the Chapter List of Figure created using the package titletoc.
How to fix and make sure captions stay within the margin?
Using package tocloft changes the heading title from the other chapters.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It is advised to show [an MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). Just by looking at a screenshot of the output, it is not easy to predict what is causing the issue.